# When would ArrayList.Itr#next() throw ConcurrentModificationException on this line?

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

This question is about the JDK 1.8.0_74. The class is `java.util.ArrayList$Itr`. An instance of this (inner) class is returned when one calls `ArrayList#iterator()` method. Specifically, my question is about the `next()` method on `Itr`:

```
850        public E next() {
851            checkForComodification();
852            int i = cursor;
853            if (i >= size)
854                throw new NoSuchElementException();
855            Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
856            if (i >= elementData.length)
857                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
858            cursor = i + 1;
859            return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
860        }
```

I understand the rationale [1] for the `checkForComodification` call on line# 851. I also understand the `(i >= size)` check [2] on line# 853.

**But, what is the situation that check `if (i >= elementData.length)` on line# 856 is guarding against?**

In a single threaded code, I am not able to make some code fail with `ConcurrentModificationException` **on line# 857**.

[1]: Structural modification after iterator creation fails:

```
static void coMod() {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(4);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        Iterator<Integer> itr = list.iterator();
        list.remove(0); //structural modification after iterator creation
        if (itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("wait, there's more!");
            itr.next(); // modification while iterating -- 
                        // fails at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
        }
    }
```

[2]: Fails after Iterator has reached the end

```
static void noHasNext() {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(4);
    Iterator<Integer> itr = list.iterator();
    itr.next(); // unguarded next call -- 
                // fails at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:854)
}
```

Comment: "In a single threaded code" - that may be the important factor here...

Comment: I see, but `ArrayList` is not thread safe; so does it need to have that check?

Comment: It's just a debugging prop - in fact it even mentions that in the Javadoc intro here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Maybe if the element array grows by additions from another thread, the new value for `size` is propagated to the thread that calls `next` but that thread still sees the old value of `ArrayList.this.elementData`...? Sounds rather far fetched to me but that's the best I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that could only occur in a multi-threaded situation.

I believe thread 1 would have to stop immediately before executing line 855. Thread 2 would come along and set ArrayList.this.elementData to a new (smaller) array.

It's a cheap check to provide a better exception than the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception that would be thrown otherwise. It's theoretically possible an optimizer could even detect the array bounds are being checked explicitly and omit the check for ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: It is not true that "This is something that could only occur in a multi-threaded situation".

Comment: @LewBloch Explain how it could happen in a single threaded situation. The question is specifically asking when the exception is thrown on line 857, not in general. checkForComodification() is the normal (single-threaded) check for modification.